# Autofill form apex-oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Clicking on the Create button opens a form for us. There is a P1_Item in the form, P1_date. In the P1_Item it is necessary to specify an object. This object is in the form in the list of values. I want the date to be automatically selected when selecting one of the objects from the list.

In the "Default" I write:

```
select TO_CHAR(data, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from test where  OBJECT =:P1_OBJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dynamic action on `P1_OBJECT` which would **Set value** for the `P1_DATE` item, using query you posted.

Comment: Try **Source** instead of "Default". Make sure to set "Used" to "Always, replacing ..:"

Comment: But I can't use Source in the form, it's not available to me

Comment: Then use dynamic action, as I told you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, I created a dynamic action, provided that P1_object will change, P1_data should set value  my request

Comment: Make sure you set 'page values to submit' in your PL/SQL dynamic action http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html